# Invoke-WebRequest progress becomes irresponsive/paused while downloading the file from powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting and am trying to automate a build dependencies download and execution. I am implementing a .bat file for the same and execute it from terminal. Invoke-webrequest is used for downloading dependencies.

I am facing a problem while trying to download a large file . the download is stopping in background if the system is left idle.
I have written commands in a .bat file and triggered it from Powershell. I am currently using Invoke-webrequest as I am able to send credentials too in a oneliner.

```
@REM %DebugUri%- url to downloadfile
@REM %debugfeature% - output file path.
@REM USERID , PASSID provided in previous steps.

powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %DebugUri% -OutFile ./%debugfeature% -UseBasicParsing -Credential (New-Object PSCredential('%USERID%', (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String '%PASSID%')))"
```

It is working fine for downloading small files(~50MB). but when I tried downloading large files (~1GB) and leaving the system idle for sometime. Download progress is paused and the PowerShell terminal becomes unresponsive.Download is stopped too(no network activity as per task manager).

The download is working fine if the PowerShell screen is in the foreground and the system is kept active during the whole time(not sure if it is related)

Is there any attribute I need to add to keep the download progress active? or any other process i can use to download the file using .bat script.
let me know if you need any further info.
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue the other day. Interestingly enough, something with the way that the download progress is checked/updated massively slows down the actual download itself. You should and might have to disable the download progress in order to get a decent download speed. You can do this like so:

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
# your code here
$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'
```

Alternatively, you can use the underlying WebClient class to make the request as well which is what I did:

`Invoke-Expression (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://mydownloadpath.com')`